# x vs. t and y vs. t graphs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, graphing-functions

How would I go about sketching the x vs t and y vs t graphs for the following picture:

[image]

Our class didn't get the opportunity to solve these types of questions, so I'm on my own for this one. My thinking is that, for the first one at least, that it would need to be parametrized in some way because it looks like a circle. Since it's a circle of radius $4$, the differential equation must be related to the general formula of the circle. My problem is that I'm not sure where to even start since I'm not given any information about t, but I strongly believe that parametrization should play a key role here.

Any suggestions on how to initially proceed, at least for the first problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first one, try $$x' = y, y' = - x, x(0) = 0, y(0) = 4$$

This results in $$x(t) = 4 \sin  t \\ y(t) = 4 \cos t$$

You should be able to draw those two solutions for $x(t)$ and $y(t)$.

Comment: Hi Moo. How did you come up with the first set of equations: $x' = 4y$, $y' = -4x?$ I'm not seeing this clearly just yet.

Comment: Ah **now I see it**. I guess I got to brush up on my linear algebra skills, but this should be enough to get me started on the second one. I off for tonight, but I will report back and write down my solutions for the rest of the problems.

Comment: @JohnSmith: I had some slight typos that I corrected in the answer as you only need the eigenvalues to be $\pm~ i$.

Comment: Hi Moo. Yes I noticed that when I was going over the problem. Now, for the second problem, this looks like a golden spiral? I've been doing some independent research and have came across a wide variety of spirals that could perhaps match the image for part b. The golden spiral is what closely resembles the image, or so I believe.

Comment: If I read the instructions correctly, I think they want you to do something like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J8TE7o2EJfI

Comment: Hi Moo. I'll take a look at the link tonight.